# Using XMLElement(Order) Attribute with XMLArrayItem Attribute

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize an object with primitive types and complex objects to an `XML` format that uses `XMLArrays` for the objects.  I'm having difficulty with this as I need to order each XML element in a specific order but I'm getting the following error message:

```
"XmlElement, XmlText, and XmlAnyElement cannot be used in conjunction with XmlAttribute, XmlAnyAttribute, XmlArray, or XmlArrayItem."
```

Here's my code:

```
 public class XMLClaimFieldInfo
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 2)]
    public string ClaimDataType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 3)]
    public int UIGridRowLoc { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 4)]
    public int UIGridColLoc { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 5)]
    public int TabOrder { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 6)]
    public string DefaultValue { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 7)]
    public int? UIGridRowSpan { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 8)]
    public int? UIGridColSpan { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 9)]
    public string Format { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 10)]
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 11)]
    [XmlArrayItem("XMLClaimFieldSelectOption")]
    public List<XMLClaimFieldSelectOption> ClaimFieldSelectOptions;
    [XmlElement(Order = 12)]
    [XmlArrayItem("XMLFieldValidation")]
    public List<XMLFieldValidation> FieldValidations { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Order = 13)]
    [XmlArrayItem("XMLClaimFieldObjectMap")]
    public List<XMLClaimFieldObjectMap> ClaimFieldObjectMaps = new List<XMLClaimFieldObjectMap>();
```

I'm guessing this is because I'm using `XMLElement` attribute with the `XMLArrayItem` attribute?  Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `[XmlArray(Order=13)]` in place of `[XmlElement(Order = 13)]`.

Comment: Can you add more explanation as to why this would work?

Comment: XmlArray can be used with XmlArrayItem. XmlArray also has the Order property as needed by the OP's code.